# Populate data in entity field in symfony2?

Tags: symfony, twig

I want to show data in entity field but data from database not show in entity field when I open edit form, here is my code:

```
<?php

namespace Projects\ProjectsBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
class MilestonesType extends AbstractType
{
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('name')
        ->add('description')
        ->add('dueDate','datetime',array('label' => false,'data'=>new \DateTime(),'attr'=>array('style'=>'display:none;')))
       ->add('companyName', 'entity', array('class' => 'ClientsClientsBundle:Company','query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
    return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')

        ->orderBy('u.id', 'ASC');

},
  'label' => 'Company id',
'property' => 'companyName',
))
        ->add('firstname', 'entity', array('class' => 'ClientsClientsBundle:Clients','query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
    return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')

        ->orderBy('u.id', 'ASC');

},
  'label' => 'Client id',
'property' => 'firstname',
))

        ->add('isPrivate','choice', array('choices' => array('yes' => 'yes', 'no' => 'no')))
        ->add('startedAt','datetime',array('label' => false,'data'=>new \DateTime(),'attr'=>array('style'=>'display:none;')))
        ->add('completedOn','datetime',array('label' => false,'data'=>new \DateTime(),'attr'=>array('style'=>'display:none;')))
        ->add('createdDatetime','datetime',array('label' => false,'data'=>new \DateTime(),'attr'=>array('style'=>'display:none;')))
        ->add('updatedDatetime','datetime',array('label' => false,'data'=>new \DateTime(),'attr'=>array('style'=>'display:none;')))
    ;
}

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Projects\ProjectsBundle\Entity\Milestones'
    ));
}

public function getName()
{
    return 'projects_projectsbundle_milestonestype';
}
}
```

and here is my edit form:

```
<form action="{{ path('milestones_update', { 'id': entity.id }) }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(edit_form) }}>
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT" />
    {{ form_widget(edit_form) }}
    <p>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Next <i class="icon-chevron-right"></i></button>
    </p>
</form>
```

Comment: And if you var_dump/die in the query_builder function, does it show?

Comment: Can you show your controller action too please who call the form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first you need to fetch the entity

```
$milestone = $this->em->getRepository('Projects\ProjectsBundle\Entity\Milestones')->find($id);
```

next you need to pass the entity to create the form with MilestonesType as type base

```
$form = $this->createForm(new MilestonesType(), $milestone);
```

then create the form view

```
$form->createView();
```